# Visual C++ linking a textbox to two buttons in a class

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I would like to make a new class that ties a textbox and two buttons together. I can't post a picture because I don't have the reputation.

Basically it is a textbox that only accepts digits and when the button is clicked it either increments or decrements depending on which button it is. I'm aware that this sounds like a numericUpDown control and I should just use one of them but for certain reasons I can't.

The way I currently have it set up is that the textbox may only accept digits within a range and the clickevent for the buttons is to increment or decrement the textbox number.

This however takes a lot of jumping around code and linking the sender of the click to the right textbox etc.

```
if (sender) { 
   TextBox^ senderBox = (TextBox^)sender;
         if (senderBox->Text != "") {
                if (senderBox->Name == "waitTimeNum" && System::Convert::ToInt32(waitTimeNum->Text) > waitTimeMax ){
                    this->waitTimeNum->Text = System::Convert::ToString(System::Convert::ToInt32(waitTimeMax));
                }
                else if (senderBox->Name == "waitTimeNum" && System::Convert::ToInt32(waitTimeNum->Text) < waitTimeMin ){
                    this->waitTimeNum->Text = System::Convert::ToString(System::Convert::ToInt32(waitTimeMin));
                }
                else if (senderBox->Name == "amplitudeNum" && System::Convert::ToInt32(amplitudeNum->Text) > amplitudeMax ){
                    this->amplitudeNum->Text = System::Convert::ToString(System::Convert::ToInt32(amplitudeMax));
                }
                else if (senderBox->Name == "amplitudeNum" && System::Convert::ToInt32(amplitudeNum->Text) < amplitudeMin ){
                    this->amplitudeNum->Text = System::Convert::ToString(System::Convert::ToInt32(amplitudeMin));
                }
                else if (senderBox->Name == "durationNum" && System::Convert::ToInt32(durationNum->Text) > durationMax ){
                    this->durationNum->Text = System::Convert::ToString(System::Convert::ToInt32(durationMax));
                }
                else if (senderBox->Name == "durationNum" && System::Convert::ToInt32(durationNum->Text) < durationMin ){
                    this->durationNum->Text = System::Convert::ToString(System::Convert::ToInt32(durationMin));
             }
        }
}
```

Instead I'd like to make a new class control where a textbox, and two buttons can be added and automatically set to be next to each other.

I'd like the class to have the attributes:

- maximum
- minimum
- increment value
- an up button
- a down button
- a textbox
- a name
- a 'text' (what's displayed on the form)

The buttons should then be able to be called with a method 'increment' for example and the correct textbox should increment.

I've looked into custom controls and that kind of thing but can't find anything similar to this. Does anyone have any ideas about how this can be done?

Comment: Are you looking for [`NumericUpDown` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx)?

Comment: As I said Igor I can't use NumericUpDown, but I pretty much have to reinvent it with a bit of customisation to satisfy what the customer asked for.

Comment: Create a UserControl, add the Minimum, Maximum and Value properties.